# How to sort a list according to another array to generate a new array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, numpy

I have a list with the length of n:

```
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

and a array with the size of m*n like:

```
values = array([[0. , 0.6, 0.3, 0.1],
                [0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3],
                [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]])
```

I wish to sort labels by each line of values and to generate a new m*n array like:

```
labels_new = [['a', 'd', 'c', 'b'],
                ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a'],
                ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) function. Just use a numpy array for preserving the labels and then a simple indexing:

```
In [6]: labels = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])                                                                                                                                                             

In [7]: labels[np.argsort(values)]                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[7]: 
array([['a', 'd', 'c', 'b'],
       ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a'],
       ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: Is it possible to reverse the list? I need to sort labels by values from the maximum to the minimum.

Comment: @zhangboyu just reverse the order of argsort's result columns'; `np.argsort(values)[:,::-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Function `argsort` arranges an array in a srted order and returns the corresponding array of indexes. That array can be used to reorder the labels:

```
[array(labels)[np.argsort(v)].tolist() for v in values]
#[['a', 'd', 'c', 'b'], 
# ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a'], 
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```